# Detect Kindle Fire in CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, kindle-fire

I have a website based on Twitter Bootstrap.  Whenever I move around the site on a Kindle Fire the nav-bar, which is meant to be fixed to the top of the viewport, takes a second to catch up and move there.  It looks ugly as. The navbar stays fixed on the viewport on all other devices - ipad, samsung s3, desktop.

Is it possible to detect the Kindle Fire via CSS or javascript so that I can fix the navbar to the page rather than the viewport for misbehaving browsers?

Comment: This is worth a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063427/how-can-i-detect-kindle-fire-with-javascript

Comment: Presumably there's no way of switching off silk acceleration from JS ?

Comment: The kindle user can, but I don't think it's possible externally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sniff the user agent for the Silk browser with javascript. e.g.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Silk") !== -1) {
    // This is the Kindle Fire's Silk browser.
}
```